# EdgeJS Fails On Win2008 R2

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

A simple C# console application fails to run on a Windows 2008 R2 server with .Net 4.5.2 and VC++ 2013 Redist installed.

The code is below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     try
     {
         var func = Edge.Func(@"return function (data, callback) {callback(null, 'Node.js ' + process.version + ' welcomes ' + data);}");    
         var result = func(".Net");
         Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
     }

        Console.Read();
}
```

This is the error message

```
module.js:356
Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                             ^
Error: The specified module could not be found.
C:\EdgeTest\edge\x86\edge.node
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object. (C:\EdgeTest\edge\edge.js:40:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Build Platform to x64 got the code to work. It was on AnyCPU beforfe and edgejs was always loading the x86 version of edge.node.

Comment: I did the same thing, it didn't help :(